# Column locking in innodb?

Tags: mysql, database, database-administration, innodb, locking

I know this sounds weird, but apparently one of my columns is locked.

```
select * from table where type_id = 1 and updated_at < '2010-03-14' limit 1;

select * from table where type_id = 3 and updated_at < '2010-03-14' limit 10;
```

the first one would not finish running, while the second one completes smoothly. the only difference is the type_id

Thanks in advance for your help - i have an urgent data job to finish, and this problem is driving me crazy

Comment: Is it possible that type_id: 1 simply has a large amount of rows in it?  Perhaps the query is running, and simply has a huge amount of results to process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you look at the `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` and see what other threads are accessing the system, and kill off the ones that might be using the row.

InnoDB has row-level locking, not column level. The fact that you changed the type_id means that it has selected a different row, and that row is locked.